# Underscore: Calling _.sample on an array of arrays throwing an error

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of arrays, much like:

```
[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]...]
```

I want to sample N elements of the array using Underscore's _.sample method:

```
exampleArr = [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]...]
_.sample(exampleArr, 3) // [[0,3], [1,2], [3,4]]
```

My implementation is as simple as it gets, and I'm sure the Underscore file is loaded correctly--I can use other Underscore functions on the array (such as shuffle), just not sample.

I'm getting a weird error, almost like Underscore can't handle sampling an array of arrays.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) {
  if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
} has no method 'sample'
```

Any idea what my problem is?

Comment: I'd check your console -> network and make sure all the files are loading correctly. It appears that it's not finding underscore.js going by has no method 'sample'

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback. It's recognizing other underscore functions, though, so I don't think it's a file loading issue. I can shuffle the array, for example. It's just not recognizing the sample method.

Comment: You could search your copy of underscore.js for sample see if the method exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using a version of underscore that doesn't have the sample function. You need to have 1.5.2. You can check your current version by typing _.VERSION. If it's anything less than that you'll need to download the version 1.5.2 or later from their page:
http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: From the change log for 1.5.2: Added a sample function, for sampling random elements from arrays.